# When I edit the title in vim markdown file, how can I disable the title to unfold automatically?

Tags: vim

I'm using vim-markdown plugin and when I edit or press `l` or `right arrow` key on a title like this
`## title` , the title  will unfold automatically and became something like

`## title
some content`

I don't want `some content` to show up when I edit `## title` or press the `l` or `right arrow` key on it, how can I do? Thanks!

Comment: which vim-markdown plugin ?

Comment: @Meninx https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that markdown plugin sets up a foldexpr or syntax folding, and when you say "unfold" you are talking about Vim's folding feature (:help folding).

If this is the case, then it is not possible to prevent editing the title from opening the fold. Vim only lets you edit unfolded text, and will automatically unfold a fold when you enter insert mode on a line in the fold.

However you can prevent the content from unfolding from any movement command that does not actually change text, using the 'foldopen' option. See :help 'foldopen' within Vim for details of what the option can do.

Comment: Thanks. After I `set foldopen -=hor`, it will not unfold automatically when I navigate.